# What is a channel exit in IBM websphere MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

What is a channel exit in IBM MQ? On my research I found three types of channel exits.

- `WMQSendExit`
- `WMQReceiveExit`
- `WMQSecurityExit`

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "exit" or "exit program" in IBM-speak is the same thing that non-IBM software might call a "callback" or a "listener". It is a way to hook in your custom code into an event generated by the software.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/exits/WMQSendExit.html

> The send exit interface allows you to examine, and possibly alter, the
>   data sent to the queue manager by the WebSphere MQ Client for Java.
>   Note: This interface does not apply when connecting directly to
>   WebSphere MQ in bindings mode.
>
> To provide your own send exit, define a class that implements this
>   interface.

Comment: When does these methods call.Assume that I have implemented a custom send exit.When is the channelSendExit(MQCXP mqcxp, MQCD mqcd, ByteBuffer byteBuffer)  calls?Is it invokes when I calls the queue.put(MQMessage) method?

Comment: Send and receive access receive all data, not just messages that are put, this includes the IBM MQ protocol data called MQ FAP.  Send/receive exits could be used for encryption or compress as an example. Send exits are called for all data transmitted from the client to the MQ queue manager, receive exits are called for all data received by the client from the queue manager.  Security exits are called when the channel to the queue manager  is started and are normally used to extend the security that MQ provides.

Comment: @JoshMc thank you very much for the explanation.This is really helpful